# register dynamic components for vue app in seperate module file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to make a js module file that imports vue component and register there.
and then inherit this component and use it for the app's main component.
I've found similar cases but the thing is, I don't use vue cli.

custom.js

```
import customMain from '/custom/components/main/main.js'; 
window.Vue.defineComponent('custom-main', customMain);
```

and in the app.js

```
import Main from '/global/components/main/main.js';
var App = createApp({
...
components: {
      'global-main': Main,
},
template: `<component :is='mainComponent'></component>`,
computed: {
       mainComponent() {
           if(this.settings.customComponent){
               return 'custom-main';
           }else{
               return 'global-main';
           }
       }
```

is this doable? what should I do to make this work?
is there other alternative way to load components dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this case is defining a plugin named `registerComponents` in the `plugins` folder : *plugins/registerComponents.js*

```
import customMain from '/custom/components/main/main.js'; 

export default {
  install: (app, options) => {
    app.component('custom-main', customMain);
  }
}
```

in `App.js` use the plugin:

```
import registerComponents  from './plugins/registerComponents'

var App = createApp({....})

App.use(registerComponents)
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it but customMain file wasn't loaded. although <custom-main>tag was present in the html. of course I corrected the typo in your comment beforehand